# How can sulfur dioxide and nitric oxide be filtered out from a waste incinerator's smokestacks?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

How can sulphur dioxide and nitric oxide be filtered out from a waste incinerator's smokestacks?
I also want to know what it looks like after it is filtered out.

Comment: Google is your friend! Search "sulfur dioxide scrubber" and pages like this come up:  https://www.envitechinc.com/sulfur-dioxide-scrubber  or   https://www.yokogawa.com/uk/library/resources/application-notes/sulfur-dioxide-scrubber-ph-control/